# Facebook Stream.Get -- How to access data in array?

Tags: php, api, facebook, get, stream

On `stream.get`, I try to

```
echo $feeds["posts"][$i]["attachment"]["href"];
```

It return the URL, but, in the same array scope where "type" is located (which returns string: video, etc), trying `$feeds["posts"][$i]["attachment"]["type"]` returns nothing at all!

Here's an array through PHP's `var_dump`: http://pastie.org/930475

So, from testing I suppose this is protected by Facebook? Does that makes sense at all?

Here it's full: http://pastie.org/930490, but not all attachment/media/types has values.

It's also strange, because I can't access through `[attachment][media][href]` or `[attachment][media][type]`, and if I try `[attachment][media][0][type]` or `href`, it gives me a string offset error.

```
["attachment"]=> array(8) {
    ["media"]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> array(5) {
            ["href"]=> string(55) "http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=1392999461587"
            ["alt"]=> string(13) "IN THE STUDIO"
            ["type"]=> string(5) "video"
```

My question is, is this protected by Facebook? Or we can actually access this array position?

Answer (score 1):

Well, once the data is returned to you, it can no longer be protected by Facebook.  You have full access to everything in that result as a regular data structure.

From the looks of it, there are multiple `href` properties throughout, so you'll want to be careful which one you're going for. `$feeds["posts"][$i]["attachment"]["href"]` is a valid element for some items, but `$feeds["posts"][$i]["attachment"]["media"][0]["href"]` is also a valid element.

There doesn't appear to be a `$feeds["posts"][$i]["attachment"]["type"]` element though, so that's why you're getting nothing for that particular item.  There is a type inside `["attachment"]["media"][0]` however, which is probably what you want.

If you are getting a string offset error when using array syntax, you've probably mixed up an element somewhere.  Strings can be accessed via array syntax.  For example:

```
$str = "string";
echo $str[1];  //echos 't'
```

You would get an offset warning if you tried to access an index that was larger than the string.  In any case, from the looks of that output, `$feeds["posts"][$i]["attachment"]["media"][0]["type"]` should work.

Comment: This was solved ;D I found that media, contained a array, so simply done some foreach loop, to access the values. Thanks guys!